# splunk to find status report of each student

Tags: splunk

Index =’sqat’

Time,

Event

{

“Exam -type” : “Annually”

Exams : { “Message” : Failed in Maths exam ,Result:Failed, “Name” : s1, }

SubjecctName: Maths

}

{

“Exam -type” : “Quarterly”

Exams : { “Message” : Failed in Maths exam ,Result:Failed, “Name” : s2 }

SubjecctName: Maths

}

{

“Exam -type” : “semi - Annually”,

Exams : { “Message” : Failed in Maths exam ,Result:Failed, “Name” : s3 }

SubjecctName: Maths

}

{

“Exam -type” : “semi - Annually”

Exams : { “Message” : “Passed in Maths exam” ,”Result”:”Passed”, ’Name’ : “s4”}

SubjecctName: Maths

}

Statusreport of each student in last 30 days, last 1 day ( Count no of exams passed and failed by each student)

1. S1
2. S2
3. S3

Search | spath=Exams | mvexpand Exams | rename Exams as _raw | stats count by Result,Name

when i am trying to calcuate the output i am getting aggregates for the exams passed

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read this, [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't understand.  How can you spath it since it isn't valid json?